# Three player mahjong: scoring clarifications

Tags: mahjong

We didn't have a fourth player for some time so we switched from riichi to three player version with korean\japanese rules as described on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_player_mahjong) (I guess that's the most popular version for 3 players).

But I got a bit confused with scoring here. In riichi you just use sticks\chips, but here it's completely different and it seems normal for players to go negative on points for a portion of a game. So my question on scoring actually consists of two minor:

- With what score people begin? How do they track score if not using sticks?
- How much exactly pays discarder? And how much players pay on tsumo (self-draw)?

How we did it:
We started with 0 points for each player, so someone definetely went negative on other's victory. We just tracked the results on paper. On tsumo both players payed game points + bonus points, on ron only discarder payed full (game points + bonus points). I know that's most probably not right as per [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_player_mahjong#Discarder_pays), but later in [Recap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_player_mahjong#Recap) it says:

> Only winner scores, taking his total score (game points and bonus
>   points) from each player with no doubling of any kind. Discarder pays
>   the other players score and only the bonus points if the player was
>   ready to win (waiting for one piece with a legal minimum game points
>   hand to be acquired).

Which confuses me, to be honest.